# Почему здесь ошибка? БД northwind, все таблицы существуют

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_name 
FROM customers
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT customer_id FROM orders
            WHERE order_id = order_details.order_id
            AND quantity > 40)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: order_details надо заджоинить

Comment: я заджоинил до этого там код без подзапросов, чисто на джоинах. Я знаю как это написать с использованием ANY, но не понимаю почему оно с WHERE EXISTS не работает

Comment: Потому что так работает любая СУБД. Сначала берутся таблицы из FROM, JOIN. А только потом из этих таблиц делается фильтрация по WHERE. order_details нет ни в FROM, ни в JOIN.